A star's magnitude $M$ and intensity $I$ satisfy $M=6-2.5\log\frac{I}{I_0}$. Find the ratio of intensities between stars of magnitude $1$ and $3$.
My textbook doesn't go into how to solve this question.

The magnitude of a star is given by the equation
$$M=6-2.5\log\frac{I}{I_0}$$
where $I_0$ is the measure of the faintest star, and $I$ is the actual intensity of the star being measured. The dimmest stars are of magnitude $6$, and the brightest are of magnitude $1$. Determine the ratio of intensities between stars of magnitude $1$ and $3$.

The answer to the question in the textbook is

Magnitude $1$ is about $6.3$ times as intense as magnitude $3$.

How do they arrive at the answer?

Let $I_1$  and $I_3$ be intensities: Substitute in equation. You get two equations. Subtract one  from other and you will get the ratio $\frac{I_1}{I_3}$

Let $I_M$ represent the intensity of of a star with magnitude $M$
$$ 3 = 6 - 2.5\log \frac {I_3}{I_0}$$
$$ 1 = 6 - 2.5\log \frac {I_1}{I_0}$$
subtracting ...
$$ 2 = 2.5 \log \frac{I_1}{I_0}- 2.5\log \frac {I_3}{I_0}$$
$$\frac 2{2.5} = \log\frac {I_1}{I_3}$$
$$\frac {I_1}{I_3}= 10^{0.8}\approx 6.3$$
